# Navigating to a page on load in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working on user registration setup and stuck on a problem where I am not able to redirect from a page 'localhost:3000/activate/tokenNo.'(Activation.jsx file) on load to my main page (App.jsx file) .

Here is my activation.jsx file :

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";


const Activate = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        navigate('/')
    }, [navigate])

    return (
        <div>Activation Page</div>
    )
}

export default Activate;
```

Here is my App.jsx file :

```
import React from 'react';

export const App = () => {
  return <div>Dashboard</div>;
};
export default App ;
```

My activationController.js file :

```
exports.activationController = (req,res) => {
    const {token} = req.body 
    if(token){
        //Verify the token is valid or not or expired
    jwt.verify(token , process.env.JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION , 
        (err , decoded) => {
            if(err){
                return res.status(401).json({
                    error: "Expired Token , Signup again"
                })
            }
            else{
                //if valid save to database
                //Get name email password from token
                const {name , email , password} = jwt.decode(token)
        
                const user = new User({
                    name , 
                    email ,
                    passsword
                })
        
                user.save((err,user) => {
                    if(err){
                        return res.status(401).json({
                            error: errorHandler(err)
                        })
                    }
                    else{
                        return res.json({
                            success: true , 
                            message: "Signup successful",
                            user
                        })
                    }
                })
        
            }
        })
        
    }
    else{
        return res.json({
            message: "error happening please try again"
        })
    }
    
}
```

In my auth.routes.js

```
router.post('/activation', activationController)
```

I recieved an error in my console --> index.tsx:25 No routes matched location "/activate/tokenNo."

My reference folder --> https://github.com/Mohammed-Abdelhady/FULL-MERN-AUTH-Boilerplate

Comment: You could use a mounting `useEffect` hook or just render a redirect to do this.... but why? If you're not actually rendering anything for `Page1` component then it's better to handle a redirect at the router/route level. Can you share your routing code (*router and routes rendering the components you are working with*)?

Comment: I am working on a registerUser setup which sends the verify linkby mail to user and by clicking user is redirected to activation page than the main page . Here is my Activation file where I am asking to navigate ---->  https://pastebin.com/Ufv7A7Zw

Comment: Well, assuming you've a proper routing context that code should navigate when the `Page1` component mounts. What isn't working?

Comment: @DrewReese the page isn't navigating to "/" --> endpoint

Comment: Where is it navigating to then, what is the result? Are there any errors? Can you update your question to include all relevant code you're working with? I.E. the router and routes, and all between that and this `Page1` component that is trying to imperatively navigate?

Comment: No errors , but a warning --> index.tsx:25 No routes matched location "/activate/TokenNumberOfUser" . Here is my index.js --> https://pastebin.com/QHZTwbNx , my activate.jsx --> https://pastebin.com/Ufv7A7Zw  ,  ActivationController.jsx --> https://pastebin.com/i1PtqztB and I am navigating to App.jsx --> https://pastebin.com/Swu9PYa5

Comment: Please add all relevant code as a properly formatted code snippet and ***not*** as a link to an external resource. Future readers should be able to get all the context they need directly from the post. I don't see any route for path `"/activate/*"` to match that warning. Where is *that* path even coming from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241939/discussion-between-dodo-96-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 1):

You may need "Navigate( to="where to go") instead. Leaving the dependencies open in useEffect will make the code run only once at load time. If you include [navigate] it will run every time. Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but Router/Routes/Route may be a better mechanism. If you are doing login/registration, in your login you would have a Link to your registration page. Then you could setup 2 routes, one for Login and one for Registration.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";


const Activate = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        Navigate( to='/');
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>Activation Page</div>
    )
}

export default Activate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Often we require to perform some extra action on component or page render initially.

Like, Data fetching, etc.

To implement like this we can **use the useEffect hook from react** and state our execution into it.

I can't see the useNavigate hook in the latest version of react-router-dom so we can use the useHistory hook.

For Example:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const App = () => {
    const history = useHistory();

    useEffect(() => {
        history.push('Page2URL')
    }, [history])

    return (
        <div>Page1</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: It is not working sir , here is my file --> https://pastebin.com/Ufv7A7Zw

Comment: @Dodo96, I have updated my answer please have a look at that and try with it.